# Product of prime factors of a number, less than that number

Tags: python, prime-factoring, number-theory

First of all, I apologise for the title, I did not know how to put my problem in words. Well, here it is:

For an integer `a` greater than 1, let `F` be a sorted list of prime factors of `a`. I need to find all tuples `c` (filled with whole numbers), such that length of each tuple is equal to the size of `F` and `(F[0] ** c[0]) * (F[1] ** c[1]) * (...) < a`. I should add that I write in Python.

Example:

```py
a = 60
F = [2,3,5]

# expected result:

C = {(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0),
(0, 2, 1), (0, 3, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1),
(1, 2, 0), (1, 3, 0), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0), (3, 0, 0),
(3, 0, 1), (3, 1, 0), (4, 0, 0), (4, 1, 0), (5, 0, 0)}
```

I generated this result using `itertools.product()`, specifically:

```py
m = math.floor(round(math.log(a, min(F)), 12))
for i in itertools.product(range(m + 1), repeat=len(F)):
    if math.prod([F[j] ** i[j] for j in range(len(F))]) < a: print(i)
```

I think it works but it's inefficient. For example number 5 appears only in one tuple, but was checked many more times! Is there any way to make it faster? I would use multiple `while` loops (with `break` statements) but since I don't know what is the length of *F*, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Hi Michal ! For me to understand the problem you want to solve : are you trying to get all divisors of `a` ? Do you have the prime factors decomposition of `a` at hand ? Is `c[i]` the exponent of the factor `F[i]` in the current divisor of `a` ?

Comment: I'm not trying to get all divisors of `a`, sadly. For example the last tuple - `(5,0,0)` is equivalent to 2^5 * 3^0 * 5^0 = 32 * 1 * 1 = 32, which is not a divisor of 60, but it is less than 60 and set of prime factors of 32 is a subset of prime factors of 60.


And I have a good function to do a prime factorization of `a`.

Comment: So for a factor `f` of `a` the max exponent will be `n` such that `f**n<=a<f**(n+1)` ?

Comment: One correction: `f**n<a<=f**(n+1)`. And then f is a max exponent, but it won't work in all cases, e.g. for `f = 2` max exponent is 5, but 2^5 * 3^1 * 5^0 > 60 (that is why tuple `(5,1,0)` is not included in my *expected result*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You base all your `range` limits on just `min(F)`.  Let's customize each to the `log(a, factor)` to reduce the cases:

```
from math import ceil, log, prod
from itertools import product

a = 60
F = [2, 3, 5]

ranges = [range(0, ceil(log(a, factor))) for factor in F]

C = []

for powers in product(*ranges):
    if prod(F[i] ** power for i, power in enumerate(powers)) < a:
        C.append(powers)

print(C)
```

By my measure, your code generates 216 test cases to come up with 25 results, but the above code only generates 1/3 of those test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over all the "valid" tuples with a generator, like so:

```
def exponent_tuples(prime_factors, limit):
    def next_tuple(t):
        n = math.prod(f ** tt for f, tt in zip(prime_factors, t))
        for idx, (f, tt) in enumerate(zip(prime_factors, t)):
            n *= f
            if n < limit:
                return (0,) * idx + (tt + 1,) + t[idx + 1 :]
            n //= f**(tt+1)
        return None

    t = (0,) * len(prime_factors)
    while t is not None:
        yield t
        t = next_tuple(t)


for t in exponent_tuples([2, 3, 5], 60):
    print(t)
```

The idea here is to basically increment the tuple entries like digits of a number and have the respective digit roll over to zero and carry the 1 whenever you reach the defined limit.

I'm pretty sure this does exactly what you want, except for maybe the order in which it yields the tuples (can be adjusted by modifying the `next_tuple` function)

EDIT: Simplified the code a bit

Answer (score 0):

The almost cooked proposition would go like this (shell execution)

```py
>>> max_exponents(42,[2,3,7])
[5, 3, 1]
>>> #pick 2
>>> max_exponents(42//2**2,[3,7])
[2, 1]
>>> #pick 1
>>> max_exponents(42//(2**2*3**1),[7])
[0]
```

I'm almost done. This will adapt to any number of factors !

Answer (score -1):

Somehow your proposition reduces to this (more readable form ?)

```py
import math as m 
import pprint

a = 60
prime_factors = [2,3,5]

exponents =list(map(lambda x:m.floor(m.log(a,x)),prime_factors))
rez = []
for i in range(exponents[0]+1):
    for j in range(exponents[1]+1):
        for k in range(exponents[2]+1):
            if 2**i*3**j*5**k <= a:
                rez.append((i,j,k))
pprint.pprint(rez)
```

and you would  like to know wether there's a way to make if faster (with less tests). So we're no more on the implementation side, but more on the conception (algorithm) side ?

For example, once the first exponent `c[0]` has been chosen, the next ones should be selected amongst the one fitting in  a//(2**c[a]) as the other answerer proposed i guess

Comment: Well, yes. I'd like to find more efficient algorithm (if there is one).

Comment: Your solution is what I'm trying to avoid. You have three `for` loops and no guarantee that `len(prime_factors)` is also 3.

Comment: I understand that, my proposition was not meant as a solution, just as a clarification. From there on, we can try to tweek it to do better